# How to debug RediSearch Json indexing issues?

Tags: redis, redisearch

When indexing json with RediSearch documents won't be indexed if the type mapping is incorrect, like if a number is mapped as TEXT or similar.

Most often the symptom is that the index is just empty or missing data even when there are json documents in the database.

Troubleshooting this by trial and error through the profiler is time-consuming. The only way I found is to match documents with the index definition (FT.INFO) manually and try to spot the mismatch.

Is there a better way? Like a log or way to get a message where I can look for issues with indexing documents?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing the same issue now

Comment: I also am very frustrated regarding this issue right now. Any solution?